# Trekking in Nepal

Tags: trekking, nepal

What is the condition of Nepal after Earthquake in Nepal.
A trekking Company Named Budget Trekking.
Says its good to travel. But i am really confused what to do? Can anyone help me out

Comment: What are you confused about?  Nepal has been open for tourism since the earthquake.